# XSLT: adding xmlns:prefix attribute at runtime to a stylesheet that is in an aliased namespace

Tags: xslt

I have an XSLT stylesheet that creates another XSLT stylesheet. The output XSLT, that is created by the first, need to have xmlns prefix/namespace definitions that will be set at run-time. Below is an example of what I tried, but it is not working. I don't know how to set the xmlns:$somePrefix=$someNamespace on the alias-xsl:stylesheet when using params. Any ideas on how to do this? I also added an example of desired output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:alias-xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/TransformAlias" version="2.0">
  <xsl:param name="someNamespace"/>
  <xsl:param name="somePrefix"/>
  <xsl:namespace-alias result-prefix="xsl" stylesheet-prefix="alias-xsl"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <alias-xsl:stylesheet version="2.0">
      <xsl:attribute name="{$somePrefix}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$someNamespace"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <alias-xsl:output method="xml"/>
      <alias-xsl:template match="/">
        <some-output>
          <alias-xsl:apply-templates/>
        </some-output>
      </alias-xsl:template>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </alias-xsl:stylesheet>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example of desired output ($somePrefix=xmlns:s and $someNamespace=http://example.com) :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
      xmlns:s="http://example.com">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <some-output>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </some-output>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following stylesheet produces the desired output (tried on http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:alias-xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/TransformAlias"
  version="2.0">
  <xsl:param name="someNamespace">http://example.com</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="somePrefix">s</xsl:param>
  <xsl:namespace-alias result-prefix="xsl" stylesheet-prefix="alias-xsl"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <alias-xsl:stylesheet version="2.0">

      <xsl:namespace name="{$somePrefix}" select="$someNamespace"/>

      <alias-xsl:output method="xml"/>
      <alias-xsl:template match="/">
        <some-output>
          <alias-xsl:apply-templates/>
        </some-output>
      </alias-xsl:template>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </alias-xsl:stylesheet>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You might want to have a look at http://www.xmlplease.com/xsl-namespace which explains the `xsl:namespace` line that was added. Note that I specified the `somePrefix` parameter value as `s` instead of `xmlns:s`.

Comment: For other people who come here: note that xsl:namespace requires XSLT 2.0. The reason the original attempt fails is that namespace nodes and attribute nodes are quite different things in the data model, and xsl:attribute can only create attribute nodes, not namespace nodes.